# Making Vitamins from Fruit of Shvi'is (Shmitta -- the 7th year)

Tags: halacha, fruits, shmita

There are certain things a person can and can't do with the fruit of shmitta and in what way they are allowed to eat it.

Could a person (or perhaps a company with the ability to produce such products) break down the fruits of shmitta to use them to make vitamins?

Comment: Seems highly unlikely. There would be plenty of waste product and it's hard to call this Derekh Achilaso.